# Unity: Gfx.UploadTexture Async

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a project in Unity that requires the loading of asset bundles, each of the asset bundles contains a Scene with multiple textured objects. Now once i actually asynchronously load in a Scene with
`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName,LoadSceneMode.Additive);`

I get a big spike in the Unity Profiler due to Gfx.UploadTexture this is done for each texture in the scene even though only one object is visible on loading in the scene. From my understanding Gfx.UploadTexture is supposed to happen the first time an object gets rendered, so since only one object is active I would expect this to happen only once and then with the other objects upon activating them.

Is there any good solution to avoid these big spikes and to not have all textures uploaded at the same time?